AT25SF081 FLASH device Status register SI SO transition
I have a second question on the AT25SF081 Flash Datasheet. I am looking at the Read Register Command 05h.
My confusion is about the waveform they have described in Figure 10-1.
Here is the question:
On the SI to SO direction switch: it looks like on cycle 7, the SI is read during the low to high transition, and then directly on the same cycle 7, SO clocks out the first bit on the high to low transition, which is then to be read on the low to high of cycle 8. Is this correct?

Figure 10-1 merely shows you the bit order.  The figure does not have enough detail to show the timing requirements.  You need to view it in conjunction with the timing information elsewhere in the datasheet.  Phrases like "cycle 7" and "cycle 8" have a fuzzy meaning.  You really need to think in terms of the number of sampling and driving clock edges.
Cycle 7 corresponds to the last bit of the byte that is sampled on the AT25SF081 SI data input pin.  Figure 13-1. Serial Input Timing shows that the SI input pin is sampled on the rising edge of the SCK clock signal.
Before the 9th rising edge of the clock (cycle 8), the AT25SF081 SO data output pin must be stable and valid for your external logic to sample it.  The timing characteristics are shown in Figure 13-2. Serial Output Timing, which shows \$t_V\$ as the output valid time.  The table in section 12.5 AC Characteristics - All Other Parameters shows that the maximum output valid time is 8ns (or 9ns, depending on your configuration).  This means that you can sample the SO pin 8ns after the falling edge of SCK, but not before that.
Refer also to section 4 Device Operation:

data is always latched in on the rising edge of SCK and always output
on the falling edge of SCK

